# Check if only one file exists with current data on bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, if-statement

How to check if  only one file exists with current date.
I have a script:

```
name="nginx.log"
data=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
current_nginx=$name.$data
cd /var/log/
for i in `ls "$name"*`; do
if [[ $i == "$current_nginx" ]]; then
    echo "only one file is exists"
else
    echo "other files is exists"
fi
done
```

I have files:

```
ls -l /var/log/nginx.log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4814275 May 12 23:59 /var/log/nginx.log.2017.05.12.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40468077 May 13 09:40 /var/log/nginx.log.2017.05.13
```

In a result of script i have:

```
bash test.sh
other files is exists
only one file is exists
```

Where i have error. I repeat. If i have only one nging.log with current date, i want get "only one file is exists". If i have more nginx.log.* files, i want to get message "other files is exists".

Comment: `ls "$name"*`? Please read comments to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43944643/3776858).

Comment: Only one with current date? Does that mean you want to check that there aren't any with other dates (all that match `"$name."*` also match `"$name.$data"*`), or that you want to count the files with the current date (the ones that match `"$name.$data"*`)?

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in `ls "$name"*`;
```

If (any of) the entries matching that glob are directories, this will list their contents too. If they aren't, or you don't want to list their contents, just use `for i in "$name"* ;` -- it's the shell that expands the glob anyway, and `ls` doesn't do anything useful here.

You can count the number of files matching a glob purely in Bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( "$name"* )
count=${#files[@]}              # take the count
for f in "${files[@]}" ; do     # or loop over them
    ...
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, my first answer was junk. Replace the for loop:

```
nfiles=$(ls "$name"* | wc -l)
if [ $nfiles = 1 ]; then
    echo "only one file exists"
else
    echo "$nfiles exist"
fi
```

`wc -l` counts the number of lines in the previous command's output.

Comment: not bad. but in this case, we calculate all files. i need see only match nginx.current_date

Comment: Ah sorry I'm reading too fast. Change `ls "$name"*` to `ls "$current_nginx"*`